# How to implement database engine UPDATE command

Tags: java, database-design

I am developing a simple database engine in Java (using text files as tables) and I have to implement code for CRUD operations. I have successfully written code for CREATE and INSERT commands already. Now I want to continue with UPDATE which should look like this:

```
UPDATE table-name SET attribute-name=literal {,attribute-name=literal} WHERE condition
```

But I have an issue here, I am stuck with "condition". How can I approach the implementation of a condition? (WHERE attr1 = something AND attr2 >= something OR . . .) I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Best regards.

Comment: I think you should clarify what do you mean by "implement". Do you mean how to represent the condition as objects? how to solve the condition given the "table" data? how to parse the condition?

Comment: I have to write code to parse (or interpret) the UPDATE command and make the changes to the data in the appropriate table based on the WHERE condition. I hope I am explaining correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` part is always the most important component of any database system. To find out all the records satisfying the conditions in `WHERE` part, you should build proper indexes for any columns included in the condition.

For example, you will find `WHERE attr1 = something AND attr2 >= something OR...`
, then columns `attr1, attr2` must have been indexed, otherwise it will take terrible long time to perform.

Index techniques may be hash index (for K-V search), B+ tree index and all their derived implementations.